# setting (custom) delegate runs into infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am trying to write a simple custom delegate for displaying multiple selection list (after referring various online tutorials, stackoverflow, Apple doc), but in the class that I want to use the delegate, the line where I set the delegate runs into an infinite loop when I run it.

I have shared the source code here
https://bitbucket.org/ikosmik/uilistviewcontroller/src/ddfcd140b52e6e59d84e58d34d601f8f850145a1/UIList?at=master

UIListViewController (where am declaring the protocols)
https://bitbucket.org/ikosmik/uilistviewcontroller/src/ddfcd140b52e6e59d84e58d34d601f8f850145a1/UIList/UIListViewController.h?at=master

And am trying to use the delegate in a UIViewController called View_Exporter

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIListViewController.h"

@interface View_Exporter : UIViewController <UIListViewDelegate, UIListViewDataSource>

  @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *viewForList; 
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIListViewController *listViewController;

@end
```

View_Exporter.m

```
#import "View_Exporter.h"


@implementation View_Exporter

@synthesize arraySelectedList;
@synthesize viewForList;
@synthesize listViewController;



#pragma mark - UIListViewController Methods

-(NSArray *) itemsForList {
    NSLog(@"View_Exporter itemsForList");
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Server", @"Memory", nil];
    return array;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.listViewController = [[UIListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIListViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.listViewController.listViewDelegate = self;
    //[self.viewForList addSubview:self.listViewController.view];
    self.listViewController.listViewDataSource = self;

}

@end
```

But this line in viewDidLoad seems to loop infinitely when I run the code :

```
self.listViewController.listViewDelegate = self;
```

Why is this looping infinitely? Am breaking my head since yesterday on this. not sure where am going wrong. can someone please help?

Comment: If your code is in an infinite loop, stop it using the debugger's pause button or a breakpoint, then step through the code to see what is happening. And you can't name your own classes beginning with UI, that is a reserved prefix for Apple, you could be clashing with private API.

Comment: Let me check with a debugger @jrturton ! Thanks for your comment. What you are saying makes sense - I'll change the UI prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written a custom setter for `listViewDelegate`, at the end of this method you do this:

```
self.listViewDelegate = delegate;
```

This just calls the setter method again. Accessing a property via `self.` is just a way of calling`[self setXX:xxx]`. In your accessor method you need to set the instance variable directly, in the normal case this would be just

```
_delegate = delegate;
```

(The _delegate instance variable is created for you automatically). You can safely remove all of your synthesize statements, they aren't needed any more.

Comment: thanks a ton, @jrturton ! It works! I didn't realize the difference between self.listViewDelegate = delegate; and _delegate = delegate; ! & I had completely forgotten that I had explicitly added setters! Thanks again!